# How do I write Java (v11) REST client library calling multiple Spring microservices in modular way?

Tags: java, spring-boot, oop, design-patterns, httpclient

I am writing a Java library that will call multiple Spring based microservices / REST endpoints to perform GET/PUT/POST etc. Planning to use OkHttpClient library call these services in sync and/or async.

Does it make sense to write a base class for establishing connection to each service?

```
public class ConnectionKlass {

  private OkHttpClient client;
  int timeout;
  int wTimeout;

  public ConnectionKlass(int timeout, boolean wTimeout){
    this.client=new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .connectTimeout(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(wTimeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .build();
  }
}
```

And then write each service client class like following?

```
public class ValidationServiceClient {
  
   private connection;

   public ServiceAClient(reqId, timeout, wTimeout) { this.connection = ConnectionKlass(..); }
   public validate(headers, body..) {...}
   public asyncValidate(headers, body..) {...}
   ...
}

public class MessageServiceClient {
  
   private connection;

   public ServiceBClient(reqId, timeout, wTimeout) { this.connection = ConnectionKlass(..); }
   public notify(eventType, message) {...}
   public asyncNotify(eventType, message) {...}
   ...
}
```

I am not new to Java but new to J2EE world. Trying to gauge what a good design / implementation would look like?
Is there a specific design pattern that I should use to maximize modularity and ease maintainability?

Comment: The information are insufficient. Are you using the microprofile standard? If so, you may want to take a look at the [microrprofile rest client standard](https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-rest-client)

Comment: Thanks @Turing85. A dumb question. All of these microservices are Spring applications which is different that JAX-RS standard. Will it not be a mismatch of specs if tomorrow this SDK is imported in a third Spring microservice for talking to the first two? A clear analogy that comes to mind is invoking AWS S3 from within EC2 SDK. Hopefully my question makes sense. Please excuse if I am missing something obvious.

Comment: Spring does not support microprofile rest client as far as I know. This is what I meant with "the information are insufficient": at that point in time, it was not clear what technology stack you were working on.